# "Free" type variables bound by functional dependencies in type synonyms

Tags: haskell, types

Given a class

```
class MonadSignal m sigs | m -> sigs where ...
```

and a class

```
class CanSignal sigs sigs' where ...
```

I want to define a type synonym like this

```
type MonadSignal' sigs m = (MonadSignal m sigs', CanSignal sigs sigs')
```

Here the `sigs'` variable isn't mentioned in the head of the `MonadSignal'` type synonym but it's there just to connect the first and the second constraint, and it's uniquely determined by `m` which *is* mentioned in the head.

Normally I think I'd be able to `forall` it on the RHS but since this is just a `Constraint` synonym, there's no actual body for the variable to appear in.

Can anything be done here? (besides putting the variable in the head and giving the wrong impression when the synonym is actually used that it's an actual "variable")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a conservative change but one solution would be to switch from functional dependencies to type families. You could make an associated family

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module TypeFamily where

class Monad m => MonadSignal m where
  type Sig m :: *
  make :: m sig

class CanSignal sigs sigs' where

type MonadSignal' sigs m = (MonadSignal m, CanSignal sigs (Sig m))
```

It's perhaps not quite so pretty as using multiparameter type classes for both but it should be just as equivalent in expressiveness and you don't have to worry about doing this "transitive closure" sort of thing.

Comment: This is a valid solution that I used before but I needed the extra flexibility I get from functional dependencies after all.

Comment: Ah thats a shame, What extra flexibility out of curiosity?

Comment: I needed a few more type parameters so their mutual dependencies get a bit more complex than what can be expressed with associated types.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I believe you have to give that wrong impression if you insist on a fundep proper (see the bottom of this answer if you'll accept a slightly different approach). I briefly thought maybe you could make `MonadSignal'` a class instead, but you wouldn't be able to give it the superclass constraint you want. You could make up for that by being really explicit with one or more `Dict` methods, but then your life will be difficult.

Although this is not relevant, it's probably better to define

```
class MonadSignal sigs m | m -> sigs
```

swapping the order of the parameters, which gets you more useful partial application and makes `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` work for your class.

---

There's another way to use type families, based on a legitimate implementation of fundeps in terms of type families:

```
class (sigs ~ Sigs m) => MonadSignal sigs m where
  type Sigs m :: * -- Or appropriate kind
  ...

type MonadSignal' sigs m = (MonadSignal (Sigs m) m, CanSignal sigs (Sigs m))
```

Comment: Yeah, as I said. I can't really use associated types for my concrete use case because I have a few more type parameters that have complex mutual dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the type synonym with a class:

```
class MonadSignal' sigs (m :: * -> *)
instance (MonadSignal m sigs', CanSignal sigs sigs') => MonadSignal' sigs m
```

In the class instance, the type variable `sigs'` doesn't appear in the class head,
so you have to use `{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}` for it to work. Although I don't believe this class can actually cause non-termination.

Comment: This bothers me on some level since it's pretty much a hack (since the instance will match anything). Actually, are you sure this works? If I have a `MonadSignal' sigs m` constraint somewhere I won't be able to use the `MonadSignal` and the `CanSignal` context because those depend on the instance.

Comment: Yes, the instance will match anything, but a type synonym can be applied to any type - it's the same exact situation. The constraint `MonadSignal'` will always be reduced immediately to the right-hand side of the instance, since the class head matches *any* types at all. I don't know if I would call this a hack - there really is no way to do something like this with type synonyms alone. You need a class or a type family.

Comment: The trouble is you don't get any superclass constraints or any methods, so the `MonadSignal'` constraint is totally worthless.